# Jupyter file path autocomplete suggestions within quotes suggests third quote

Tags: python, jupyter, autosuggest

The autosuggest shows duplicate suggestion, one with quote and another without. Since the quotes are already closed, I want to hide the first two suggestions as selecting them adds a third quote.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by extensions you have many  intelliSense extensions.
try  setting

"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": false  or
"python.languageServer": "None"